# I want to remove corner radiuses

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm developing iOS app with XCode.

My problem is a corner radius of UIViewController as below.
I want to remove it. It's shown on only iPhone7 simulator.

[image: Screenshot]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to your `UIView`'s layer and then call this function:

```
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a couple of things:

1. Corner radius;
2. Background image that incorrectly had its corners rounded; or
3. Mask applied to the layer.

If you’re having trouble identifying the specific view that this has this applied, use the view debugger. So, run the app via Xcode and then tap on the view debugger button [image].

When your views appear in Xcode’s view debugger, rotate the view and select the culprit.

[image]

Once you’ve highlighted the view of interest, you can press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or choose “Navigate” » “Reveal in Debug Navigator” from the Xcode menu , and it will highlight the view in the view hierarchy shown on the left. Or if you choose the object inspector in the right panel, you can see the class name, and if it’s one of your classes, you can click on the little arrow to the right [image] and you will be taken directly to your code.